# Backbone.js view is not responding with templates

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/CSS/jquery-ui.css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/libs/Jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/libs/Jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/libs/Underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/libs/Backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/libs/LocalStore/backbone.localStorage-min.js" ></script> 

    <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
          <div><%= macAddress %></div>
          <div><%= labelD %></div>
          <div><%= typeD %></div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.DeviceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize : function() {
          this.macAddress = this.get('macAddress');
          this.labelD = this.get('labelD');
          this.typeD = this.get('typeD');
        }
      });
      window.DevicesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
        model: DeviceModel,
        localStorage: new Store("backbone-integrator1")
      });

      window.DeviceView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',
        template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
        initialize: function () {
        },
        render: function(){
          return $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON())) ;
        }
      });  

      var data =  /* your JSON data */ [
          {
            "macAddress": "00-03-EA-0A-50-A1",
            "labelD": "Wattbox3",
            "typeD": "WB"
          },
          {
            "macAddress": "00-03-EA-0A-50-A2",
            "labelD": "Wattbox2",
            "typeD": "WB"
          }
        ];

        var integrator = _.clone(data);

      var devices = new DevicesCollection(integrator);  

      var list = new DeviceView();
      list.render();

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

I have a JSON object and I want to convert this JSON object to model and then want to display the model on screen. But the view here is not rendering, its not mapping with the template. Can anyone please look into the code and tell me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues.  First, you are never passing the collection instance to the view instance.  Second, you have a template which will render one device, so you need to render each item in the collection.  I also renamed DeviceView to DevicesView since it is now rendering each device.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/QLm5k/4/

```
window.DeviceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function() {
      this.macAddress = this.get('macAddress');
      this.labelD = this.get('labelD');
      this.typeD = this.get('typeD');
    }
  });
  window.DevicesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: DeviceModel,
    localStorage: new Store("backbone-integrator1")
  });

  window.DevicesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
    initialize: function () {
    },
    render: function(){
        // render each model in the collection
        this.collection.each(function(model){
            this.$el.append(this.template(model.toJSON())) ;
        }, this);
    }
  });  

  var data =  /* your JSON data */ [
      {
        "macAddress": "00-03-EA-0A-50-A1",
        "labelD": "Wattbox3",
        "typeD": "WB"
      },
      {
        "macAddress": "00-03-EA-0A-50-A2",
        "labelD": "Wattbox2",
        "typeD": "WB"
      }
    ];

    var integrator = _.clone(data);

  var devices = new DevicesCollection(integrator);  

  // pass collection to the view
  var list = new DevicesView({collection:devices});
  list.render();
```

Comment: hi can anyone tell me what should be added to the render function if we are specifying the url in collection.